# Django - select statement inside order_by

Tags: django, django-views

This is my queryset:

```
most_event_wins = UserEvent.objects.filter(position=1)\
        .values('user', 'user__first_name', 'user__last_name').annotate(wins=Count('user'))\
        .order_by('-wins', '(select max(created) as d from users_userevent as s '
                           'where s.user_id=users_userevent.user_id and position=1)')
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Invalid order_by arguments: ['(select max(created) as d from users_userevent as s where s.user_id=users_userevent.user_id and position=1)']
```

Can I use a SELECT statement inside an order_by? If not any solution for this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't use a select statement in the order_by.  Is there a reason you aren't using multiple annotates to accomplish this?

```
most_event_wins = UserEvent.objects.filter(position=1)\
    .values('user', 'user__first_name', 'user__last_name')\
    .annotate(wins=Count('user')).annotate(max_created=Max('created'))\
    .order_by('-wins', 'max_created')
```